# autofac - configuration to set a property value based on generic type while resolving constructor parameter

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

i have a class with below definition:

```
public class CommandBase<T>
{
    public string CommandText { get; set; }
}

public class CommandService : ICommandService
{
    public CommandService(CommandBase<SomeClass> command)
    {
        //some other code
    }
}
```

Is it possible, using Autofac, to create a configuration such that, when the constructor parameter to `CommandService` is `CommandBase<SomeClass>`, `CommandText` value be say "SomeCommand" and when it's `CommandBase<SomeOtherClass>`, `CommandText` value be say "SomeOtherCommand".

So, In short, can i configure in autofac to resolve the value of property of an object which is resolved in constructor parameter, based on generic type?

**EDIT:**

the value for command text is a long query string and comes from another singleton class.

Comment: Could you update your question to show that _actual_ use case for this? What kind of information do you want this `CommandText` to return? Is this runtime data? And what is `CommandBase<T>`? Is that a data container (like DTO or message) or something with behavior?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to change the `CommandBase` implementation

```
public class CommandBase<T>
{
    public CommandBase(CommandRetriever retriever)
    {
        this.CommandText = new Lazy<String>(() => retriever.GetCommand(typeof(T)); 
    }

    private readonly Lazy<String> _commandText; 

    public String CommandText { 
        get {
            return this._commandText.Value; 
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, based on what I understand, I would do something like this :

```
public interface ICommand
{
    String CommandText { get; }
}

public abstract class CommandBase<T> : ICommand
{
    public CommandBase(CommandRetriever retriever)
    {
        this._commandText = new Lazy<String>(() => retriever.GetCommand(typeof(T)));
    }

    private readonly Lazy<String> _commandText;

    public virtual String CommandText => this._commandText.Value;
}

public class PersonCommand : CommandBase<Person>
{
    public PersonCommand(CommandRetriever retriever) : base(retriever)
    { }
}
```

Like this your `CommandService` doesn't need to be generic anymore which simplify lot of things

```
public class CommandService : ICommandService
{
    public CommandService(ICommand command)
    {
        //some other code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is yes. You can use ***RegisterGeneric***.

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(CommandBase<>)).AsSelf();
```

If you want to register to interface -

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(CommandBase<>)).As(typeof(ICommandBase<>));
```

Comment: How the value of `CommandText` be configured to resolve based on this?

Comment: Since value for CommandText come from other another singleton class, you can just inject that singleton class to CommandBase via constructor injection.